# How to add events on .Net MAUI Handler

Tags: c#, xamarin, handler, maui

I have a Xamarin application , now migrating the project to MAUI. There is a renderer for picker and it contains the `OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)` and there are some actions inside this event. But when I'm trying to convert that into MAUI handler couldn't found any event for this. How can I achieve this on MAUI.

Here is my Custom Picker and Renderer, This renderer is for binding different value to the picker text property and dropdown list , like I want to show the item description on Picker dropdown and when the user select one need to bind the Item name on the picker text.

```
public class CustomPicker : Picker
{ 
   public CustomPicker()
   {
   }  
      public static readonly BindableProperty DisplayItemTextProperty =BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DisplayItemText),typeof(string), typeof(CustomEntry), default(string), BindingMode.TwoWay);
      public string DisplayItemText
        {
           get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayItemTextProperty); }
           set => SetValue(DisplayItemTextProperty, value);
        }
   }
```

Renderer

```
public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{  
 CustomPicker customPicker;
    public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
     {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement == null)
          {
           customPicker = Element as CustomPicker;
          }
      }
  protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
       base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
       if (Control != null && customPicker != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(customPicker.DisplayItemText))
           {
             Control.Text = customPicker.DisplayItemText;
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you converting your PickerRenderer to a PickerHandler? Well you can use my FreakyPicker as an example https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls/tree/master/MAUI.FreakyControls/MAUI.FreakyControls

Answer (score 0):

> There is a renderer for picker and it contains the OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) and there are some actions inside this event. But when I'm trying to convert that into MAUI handler couldn't found any event for this. How can I achieve this on MAUI.

MAUI has elaborated on this issue and its use cases in the official wiki, please refer to [Property Mappers](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Porting-Custom-Renderers-to-Handlers#property-mappers) for more details.

> The `PropertyMapper` is a new concept introduced by Handlers. It is a Dictionary that maps the interface's Properties to their associated Actions. It is defined in the interface of our control and it replaces everything that was done in `OnElementPropertyChanged` in `Xamarin.Forms`: